# Direct to new html page after paypal data transfer

Tags: php, paypal

When user completed paypal transaction it send them to a page on my site that processes the transaction. However the screen is white and no source code is coming up. I know the script is working up uttil the SQL statement as my db is updatting. The script should then  direct to page as indicated by its header output but I'm wondering since Paypal makes two visits to this page could that be messing this up.

Here is the return script:

```
        <?php 
    error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    // The custom hidden field (user id) sent along with the button is retrieved here. 
    if($_GET['cm']) $user=$_GET['cm']; 
    // The unique transaction id. 
    if($_GET['tx']) $tx= $_GET['tx'];
     $identity = 'TOKEN VALUE'; 
    // Init curl
     $ch = curl_init(); 
    // Set request options 
    curl_setopt_array($ch, array ( CURLOPT_URL => 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr',
      CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
      CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query(array
        (
          'cmd' => '_notify-synch',
          'tx' => $tx,
          'at' => $identity,
        )),
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
      CURLOPT_HEADER => FALSE,
      // CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => TRUE,
      // CURLOPT_CAINFO => 'cacert.pem',
    ));
    // Execute request and get response and status code
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $status   = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    // Close connection
    curl_close($ch);
    if($status == 200 AND strpos($response, 'SUCCESS') === 0)
    {

        include ("dbconnect.php");
            $query="UPDATE users SET paid='1' WHERE userid='$user'";
            $result=mysqli_query($con,$query);
            exit(); // Quit the script.
            header('Location: http://www.xxxxxxxxxxx/php/process_paypal_success.php');
    }
    ?>
```

Here's the page the return script should send the user too:

```
          <?php 
      ob_start();
      session_start();
      require_once ('verify.php'); 
      $page_title = 'settings.php';


      $sid = session_id();
      $first_name=$_SESSION['first_name'];
      $last_name=$_SESSION['last_name'];
      $email_address=$_SESSION['email_address'];


              include ("dbconnect.php");
              $query="SELECT * FROM users WHERE email_address='$email_address'";
              $result=mysqli_query($con,$query);
              $data=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
                  $userid = $data['userid'];
                  $password = $data['password'];
                  $signup_date = $data['signup_date'];
                  $last_login = $data['last_login'];

      // Check for a $page_title value:
      if (!isset($page_title)) {
          $page_title = 'User Registration';
      }

      // If no first_name session variable exists, redirect the user:
      if (!isset($_SESSION['email_address'])) {

          $url = BASE_URL . ''; // Define the URL.
          ob_end_clean(); // Delete the buffer.
          header("Location: $url");
          exit(); // Quit the script.

      }
      ?>
      <?php 
      $title="title here" ; 
      $description="You have successfully submitted your payment and registered for the event" ; 
      include( "header.php"); 
      ?>
      <body>
```

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); `then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: it's already there, not getting any errors in browser

Comment: you cant have 2 header calls, just remove `header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

Comment: @Dagon fixed that but doesn't get it working, same problem, blank screen, I'm posting the start of the url it's forwarding to

Comment: shot in the dark; try placing your `exit();` after the header. I'm not sure if that makes a difference or not, but I'm used to using/seeing it that way.

Comment: It is not recommended to handle this sort of thing on your return URL because there is no guarantee the user will make it there even with Auto-Return enabled in PayPal.  If they don't make it there the code will never run, of course.  Instead, you should use IPN which is very similar to PDT except that it happens separate from the checkout flow and will always be triggered regardless of whether or not the user makes it back to your site.

Comment: @Fred-ii- that did it!

Comment: @Rhillz great, glad to hear it, *cheers*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're exiting before the header, therefore the redirection won't happen.

Once you've exited, that's it; the rest of your code won't execute.

Therefore, change this part of your script:

```
exit(); // Quit the script.
header('Location: http://www.xxxxxxxxxxx/php/process_paypal_success.php');
```

to:

```
header('Location: http://www.xxxxxxxxxxx/php/process_paypal_success.php');
exit(); // Quit the script.
```

placing the `exit();` after the header.

Reference:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php

> *exit — Output a message and **terminate** the current script*

Sidenote: You can also just use `exit;`, the `()` isn't required.

Unless you wanted to show a message:

```
or exit("unable to open file ($filename)");
```

from the manual ^

So in your case, you cannot show an additional message since you're using a header.

---

Footnotes:

Your code is prone to an SQL injection. It would be best if you were to use a prepared statement.

Reference:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement